# An error occurred talking to the iTunes Store : message while validating App

Tags: ios, xcode4, app-store

I am trying to submit an app to the apple store via Xcode 4's in-built application loader. I created an archive, then went to itunes connect and made sure the app status is ready to upload. Then when I come to xcode and do 'Validate' or 'Submit', I just get the following message:
An error occurred talking to the iTunes Store

No details are given. Any ideas?

Update: I used the classic Application loader and submitted my app. No idea what the real issue was.

Answer (score 2):

My mbp now run Xcode4.2(4D199) on Lion, I installed the latest java for Lion. And finally I sovled this issue.

Many guys said, he can used the old Application Loader app to upload the apps. so I guess the problem is the latest Application Loader app(2.4.1 (190)), and the fact told me I am right

Okie, in short words:
Here is the solution:

1. I hope you guys do not delete the old Xcode(4.1). We Should pick up the old version Application Loader app.
   cd /Contents/Resources/Packages
   cp ApplicationLoader.pkg ~/Desktop/
   Now, you get the ApplicationLoader package.
2. Install the old one.
   Tips: you can remove the latest Application Loader app in path: `/Developer/Applications/Utilities/` or just remane it.

That's All.

Hope this way can help you and enjoy the new Xcode4.2. Also hope apple developer can saw this problem and test the latest Application Loader app more.

Answer (score 0):

If your target has any spaces or special characters, remove them as they can sometimes cause this error.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a connectivity or temporary network issue. I would check your network connection and try a bit later.