# An error occurred talking to the iTunes Store : While uploading app using app loader

Tags: app-store-connect

Unable to upload app to iTunes store. Tried solution on following links but did not work.

[An error occurred talking to the iTunes Store : message while validating App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7277398/an-error-occurred-talking-to-the-itunes-store-message-while-validating-app)

[Xcode stuck at “Your application is being uploaded”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19953161/xcode-stuck-at-your-application-is-being-uploaded/19996704#19996704)

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Knowing the exact error would be enormously helpful.